# Angular Material 7 Multi Select - Set selected value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui, angular-material2

I'm trying to set the selected value for multi select drop-down as below

//loop to make a multiple check boxes as selected & setting based on condition

```
document.getElementsByTagName('mat-pseudo-checkbox')[index].classList.add('mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked');
document.getElementsByTagName('mat-pseudo-checkbox')[index].setAttribute("ng-reflect-state","checked");
```

this only reflects the change cosmetically since when i try to retrieve all the selected checkbox through (selectionChange)=filter($event)

```
<mat-select multiple  (selectionChange)="filter($event)" formControlName="dropdown">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let info of infos" [value]="info">
      {{info}}
    </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

where the event doesn't seem to pick up the values we tried to set earlier, pls let me know how the event picks the selected values in case of mat select.

P.S: goal is to retain multi select boxes when switching between angular tabs

Comment: your sample not in angular-material2 context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set selected values with `FormControl.setValue()` function

**example.component.html**

```
<mat-select [formControl]="toppings" (selectionChange)="filter($event)" multiple [(value)]="selected" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**example.component.ts**

```
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.toppings.setValue(['Mushroom', 'Onion']);
  }


  filter(data){
    console.log(data.value);
  }
```

Please examine [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqeepn)

Comment: In v14 or later with strictly typed forms you need to set type of FormControl `toppings = new FormControl<string[] | null>([]);`

Answer (score 1):

see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqfeyj) sample.

you can set and get value with `formControl` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is working good link [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-dropdown)