# Unselect items in Angular Select

Tags: angular

Consider the following Angular select in this [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/njbmrypmqmb). The user can select multiple options. Is there any way to unselect these options from somewhere else? I'm talking about removing the tick of a specific item by clicking a button that's somewhere else on the page.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108032/2358409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play around this.

select-custom-trigger-example.ts

```
  removeTomato() {
    const values = this.toppings.value;
    const index = values.indexOf('Tomato');
    if (index > -1) {
      values.splice(index, 1);
      this.toppings.setValue(values);
    }
  }
```

select-custom-trigger-example.html

```
<p (click)="removeTomato()">remove tomato</p>
```

EDITED: you should only `setValue` if 'Tomato' is removed